# Different behavior of as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Currently I have a different behavior of the as_json method. This is why my specs do not run successfully.

```
User.first.as_json
# => {"username"=>"Joe", "created_at"=>Thu, 24 Apr 2014 09:41:17 UTC +00:00 }

User.first.created_at.as_json
# => "2014-04-24T09:41:17Z"
```

In my model I added a serializable_hash method to limit the fields in json and xml:

```
def serializable_hash(options={})
  super(only: [:username, :created_at])
end
```

My rspec behavior tests the following which results in an error:

```
it "response in json format" do
  expect(json).to eq assigns[:user].as_json
end
```

The error mention only that both timestamps are not equal:

```
-"created_at" => Thu, 24 Apr 2014 09:41:17 UTC +00:00,
+"created_at" => "2014-04-24T09:41:17Z",
```

How can I set the date time format for the member object in the first line?

Thanks for your help.

Steffen

Comment: What does your `as_json` method look like? Are you saying you customized it?

Comment: @pdobb: I added the serializable_hash method I have in my model. But this is only relevant for set the fields I like in a json output.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because they are different serializers, depending on the type of object is calling `as_json` from.

The **Time** `as_json` one is calling `xmlschema` and this is returning a format like: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S Z. Please follow the source code here (using PRY):

```
pry(main)> show-source User.first.validated_at.as_json
def as_json(options = nil)
  if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
    xmlschema
  else
    %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
  end
end

pry(main)> show-source User.first.validated_at.xmlschema
def xmlschema(fraction_digits = 0)
  fraction = if fraction_digits > 0
    (".%06i" % time.usec)[0, fraction_digits + 1]
  end

  "#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}#{fraction}#{formatted_offset(true, 'Z')}"
end
```

Whereas the **ActiveRecord** `as_json` is calling `serializable_hash` and for each field is doing finally a `to_s` that is returning this kind of format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC

```
pry(main)> show-source User.first.as_json
def as_json(options = nil)
  root = include_root_in_json
  root = options[:root] if options.try(:key?, :root)
  if root
    root = self.class.model_name.element if root == true
    { root => serializable_hash(options) }
  else
    serializable_hash(options)
  end
end

pry(main)> show-source User.first.serializable_hash
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  options = options.try(:clone) || {}

  options[:except] = Array.wrap(options[:except]).map { |n| n.to_s }
  options[:except] |= Array.wrap(self.class.inheritance_column)

  super(options)
end

pry(main)> show-source User.first.validated_at.to_s
def to_s(format = :default)
  if format == :db
    utc.to_s(format)
  elsif formatter = ::Time::DATE_FORMATS[format]
    formatter.respond_to?(:call) ? formatter.call(self).to_s : strftime(formatter)
  else
    "#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false, 'UTC')}" # mimicking Ruby 1.9 Time#to_s format
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanx @Rafa. Is there a way to set both formats to the same? I found out that a `class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` will help me for the second example. Anything like this for the first one?

Comment: It depends of what you want to get as output. If you want a JSON you can do `.to_json` in both and it will return the times in the same format.

Comment: `.to_json` is not what I want because it only reflects json output. With `serializable_hash` I can set the fields for json and xml.